# data.table/data.frame rbind not working fine

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rbind

I am using data.table 1.9.6. Here is some simple code and output:

```
df <- data.table(a=c(NA,NA,2,2),b=c(1,1,2,2))
nrow(df[is.na(a)]) + nrow(df[!is.na(a)])
# [1] 4
nrow(rbind(df[is.na(a)],df[!is.na(a)]))
# [1] 4
nrow(rbind(df[is.na(a),b := a],df[!is.na(a)]))
# [1] 6
rbind(df[is.na(a),b := a],df[!is.na(a)])
#     a  b
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3:  2  2
# 4:  2  2
# 5:  2  2
# 6:  2  2
rbind(df[is.na(a),a := b],df[!is.na(a)])
#     a  b
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3:  2  2
# 4:  2  2
# 5:  2  2
# 6:  2  2
```

essentially just `rbind` after `is.na()` and `!is.na()` gives me fine results but as soon as I try to replace `NA` values in column with other column value `rbind(df[is.na(a),a := b],df[!is.na(a)])` something breaks. Rather illogical `rbind(df[is.na(a),b := a],df[!is.na(a)])` also breaks. Can anyone explain what I am missing or is this a bug?

Further to keep things moving I tried:

```
rbind(data.frame(df[is.na(a),a := b]),data.frame(df[!is.na(a)]))
#    a  b
# 1 NA NA
# 2 NA NA
# 3  2  2
# 4  2  2
# 5  2  2
# 6  2  2
```

So this doesn't work even after I convert it to `data.frame`.

Comment: `dt[condition, col := blah]` returns the entire (now modified) `data.table` `dt`. That's why you get what you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you use `:=` which updates in-place with the condition, but returns the whole dataset ignoring the condition.

Either use this syntax to not update in-place :

```
rbind(df[is.na(a),.(a,b = a)],df[!is.na(a)])
    a  b
1: NA NA
2: NA NA
3:  2  2
4:  2  2
```

Or this to only update in-place

```
df[is.na(a),b := a]
df
    a  b
1: NA NA
2: NA NA
3:  2  2
4:  2  2
```

Comment: I'd go with `rbind(df[is.na(a)][, b := a], df[!is.na(a)])`